# Transfer Ajax data to hidden textbox in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have the folloing textboxes located in a form:

```
<input type="text" id="duration" name="duration" readonly="readonly"  style="width:0px"/>
<input type="text" id="renew" name="renew" readonly="readonly" style="width:0px"/>
<input type="text" id="accountAfter" name="accountAfter" readonly="readonly" style="width:0px"/>
```

On form post these text boxes will pass the data to the controller retrieved from the following dialog:

```
 $('#fixed').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width:600,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Fixed Account Details',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "OK": function () {
                $('#duration').val($('#duration').val());
                $('#renew').val($('#renew').is(':checked'));
                $('#accountAfter').val($('#accountAfter').val());
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

Is it possible hide these textboxes from the user whilst still passing data?

Comment: Labels don't get sent back with the form Post. Only fields do.

Answer (score 1):

Change them to hidden input elements. For example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="duration" name="duration" />
```

I think the rest of your code can stay the same, although I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish here; you're just updating the the values to themselves.

```
$('#duration').val($('#duration').val());
$('#renew').val($('#renew').is(':checked'));
$('#accountAfter').val($('#accountAfter').val());
```

Comment: already tried this but as Diodeus said labels don't get sent back with form post

Comment: Hidden inputs are not labels. They are real form fields that will get submitted during post as long as they are not disabled. Your code may not be working because of the strange value-copying I mentioned above -- can you show more of your HTML including the form?